# c# gridview select on button click

Tags: c#, select, button, gridview, click

I've got a GridView with a TemplateField set as button, I have code on the OnClick event which works fine if the row is already selected.

What I'm struggling to find is a way to select the row using the Button_Click.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="OrderSummaryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="1230px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderSummaryID" HeaderText="OrderSummaryID" 
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OrderSummaryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BariatricRequestID" HeaderText="BariatricRequestID" SortExpression="BariatricRequestID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceTypeID" HeaderText="DeviceTypeID" 
                        SortExpression="DeviceTypeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceType" HeaderText="Device Type" 
                        SortExpression="DeviceType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategory" HeaderText="Sub Category" 
                        SortExpression="SubCategory" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" 
                        SortExpression="Make" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" 
                        SortExpression="Model" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WeightLimit" HeaderText="Weight Limit" 
                        SortExpression="WeightLimit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceSearchResultStatus" HeaderText="Device Source" 
                        SortExpression="DeviceSearchResultStatus" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReqConfirmDateTime" HeaderText="Confirm Date/Time" 
                        SortExpression="ReqConfirmDateTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalDeviceAssetID" HeaderText="Internal Asset ID" 
                        SortExpression="LocalDeviceAssetID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm Order">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
                            Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rowID = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    string Source = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
    var AssetID = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;
```

Comment: Put some code on your question so that we get a better idea of the situation.

Comment: you can get using `OnSelectedIndexChanged` Event from `GridView1.SelectedRow`

Comment: I would use the position of the button inside the grid to select to row

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this piece of code for grabbing the row for which the button was clicked. This might not be the exact thing but should help you progress further.

```
 protected void buttonSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     GridViewRow gRow = ((GridViewRow)((Button)sender).parent.parent);
    }
```

Based on how much nested the button is, you would need to use the `parent` reference as per that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GridView.RowCommand Event` to handle your events. What you have to do is give your button a command name to determine which button was clicked. By using the `GridView.RowCommand Event` and a button's command name, you can retrieve selected rows.

Here is a sample.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "GetIndex")
  {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
  }
```

[MSDN link for this event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select a row via the RowCommand event, after checking for the proper CommandName, you can select the row like so:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "GetIndex")
  {
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    gvr.RowState = DataControlRowState.Selected;
   }
}
```

Simply setting the RowState will do the trick (as long as you can determine the row you are on beforehand.